# Controlling access with web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, web-config, authorization

I am trying to control access to my website with windows integrated.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
 <system.web>
  <authentication mode="Windows"/>
   <authorization>
     <deny users="?"/>
     <allow roles="DOMAIN\The_group_that_can_access_it"/>
   </authorization>
   ...
 </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Except that, this code isn't working. I can access it if im a member of that group or not. What is wrong?

I looked through some code, and thought maybe I needed to switch the `?` for a `*`, but then that seems to just deny everything.

Thanks,

Comment: You denied just anonymous user(?) , While you need deny Every user (*)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not have an explicit deny statement, you should add the following entry to the end of the declarations:

```
<deny users="*" />
```

And you can remove the `<deny users="?"/>` which is denying unauthenticated users. The final `<deny users="*" />` will deny them anyway. Then only your group should have access. The final outcome should be:

```
<authorization>
    <allow roles="DOMAIN\The_group_that_can_access_it"/>
    <deny users="*"/>
</authorization>
```

As a rule of thumb, always close out your access control lists with an explicit deny all, or deny any any.

Comment: well, I did try (as mentioned) using the `*` instead, but this still did not work... does the actual order of the statements matter? (allow roles first, deny second?)

Comment: Yes, allow the roles first then deny everyone else.

Comment: Random, your exactly right. I would not have thought it mattered. Thanks